# Переопределение виртуального метода в разделе private

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Есть родительский класс с виртуальным методом, записанным в разделе `private`, и есть унаследованный от него класс, переопределяющий этот метод. Когда родительский класс в том же модуле, что и унаследованный, это работает нормально. Когда он в другом модуле, появляется ошибка компилятора:

> Method not found in base class...

Как решить проблему?

Comment: перенести виртуальный метод базового класса в раздел `protected`

Comment: @Igor, спасибо.

Comment: А для полноты картины - лучше использовать `strict private` и `strict protected`. Тогда видимость элементов внутри модуля и в других модулях не будет отличаться, что значительно правильнее.